# Cron jobs with firebase - Google Cloud IO error

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I just recently set up Firebase functions. After making a simple helloWorld function work, I wanted to set up a cron job following this [Google blog tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html).
I always get an error at this step:

`gcloud app deploy app.yaml \ cron.yaml`

I get following error message:

```
C:\Users\vreee\Firebase\functions-cron\appengine>gcloud app deploy app.yaml \ 
cron.yaml
WARNING: Automatic app detection is deprecated and will soon be removed. As 
an alternative, create an app.yaml file yourself using the directions at 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml (App Engine Flexible Environment) or 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref (App 
Engine Standard Environment) under the tab for your language.
Deployment to Google App Engine requires an app.yaml file. This
command will run `gcloud beta app gen-config` to generate an app.yaml
file for you in the current directory (if the current directory does
not contain an App Engine service, please answer "no").

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

This looks like a Python app.  If so, please enter the command to run
the app in production (enter nothing if it's not a python app): :
Writing [app.yaml] to [C:\].
ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
u'C:\\app.yaml'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Anyone know how to solve this? I searched and set myself with my email address (not a service account) as the owner, so the permission should be there. I just notice that it tried to create an `app.yaml` file directly under `C:\\` instead of the `functions-cron` folder containing an `app.yaml` and the `cron.yaml` file.

Would really appreciate the help!! For additional information, I am using windows..

Comment: You tagged this with [firebase], but it seems you are not actually using Firebase.  You're deploying with gcloud to standard Cloud Functions.  If you're not actually using Firebase here, please remove the tag or explain how Firebase is involved.

Comment: I am deploying it to firebase functions - at least thats the goal (as also part of the tutorial that I refered to)

Comment: The only difference between Cloud Function and Cloud Functions for Firebase is an additional SDK and tools for triggers that are unique to Firebase.  Otherwise they have the exact same infrastructure.  (FYI there is no product called "Firebase Functions".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems indeed that the Cloud SDK is trying to create an app.yaml file, which means there was no app.yaml file in your folder `C:\Users\vreee\Firebase\functions-cron\appengine`. As per the tutorial you linked, both app.yaml and cron.yaml files should be in that directory when you run the deploy command.

So your options are:

- If you have already deployed an app and your app.yaml file hasn't changed (i.e it already declares the endpoint for your cron job), you can run the following command from your `\functions-cron\appengine` folder to upload the cron.yaml file only: `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`.
- Otherwise, you need to have both files within the same folder and run the command `gcloud app deploy app.yaml cron.yaml`.

Comment: That's the thing, in the folder `appengine` there are both an app.yaml as well as a cron.yaml. I cloned the exact same project that is named in the tutorial I followed. So dont get, why a new app.yaml is tried to be created on `C:\`

UPDATE: i tried to deploy them separately...and apparently thats working now! Thanks :)

Comment: Try `gcloud app deploy app.yaml cron.yaml`, without the \ between both files.

Answer (score 0):

In order for any Google App Engine deployment to work, a configuration file named "App.yaml" is necessary. There is an article in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) about the possible parameters and configurations.

This issue doesn't looks like related to permissions to write in the cloud, but rather permissions to write in your local machine C:. My advice would be that you create the file before the deployment so gcloud doesn't need to be granted admin permissions to write in your local machine.